# Premiere Pro finishing time?

Tags: adobe-premiere

I'm working on compiling a song with a whole bunch of tracks.  I understand that it's going to take a while to export and finish the project, but it usually takes me about 5 minutes maximum to finish a 5-track song with similar set up.
The song I'm working on currently has 30 video and 33 audio tracks, so I get that it's going to take a longer time to finish, but it's been working all night on finishing the project, so more than 12 hours on exporting already, and its still showing 15+ hours of time left to finish the project.  Is this normal??  Is there anything I can do to help my computer run faster to finish the project?  I'm working with a pretty good computer and upgraded ram.
Computer is a 2015 model iMac, purchased new in 2017 with 1 tb of storage, shows 540gbs available, and 32 gbs of memory.

Comment: What's a "pretty good computer" in your book? What's the resolution of material and output? What quality settings are you using? Are you using GPU acceleration?

Comment: 2015 iMac, purchased new in 2017.  1 tb hard drive, 543 GB available.  with a 1 tb external hard  drive.  Memory upgraded to 32 GB.

Comment: all of the videos are a little more than 4 minutes total, so the final project is about 4:15 with everything lined up.

Comment: this is what the properties look like:

Comment: File Path: /Users/xxxxxx/Downloads/IMG_0403.M4V
Type: MPEG Movie 
File Size: 224.92 MB
Image Size: 1920 x 1080
Frame Rate: 29.97
Source Audio Format: 44100 Hz - compressed - Stereo
Project Audio Format: 44100 Hz - 32 bit floating point - Stereo
Total Duration: 00:04:03:20
Pixel Aspect Ratio: 1.0
VR Projection: None

Comment: sorry, I'm realizing that hitting "enter/return" submits the comment.

Comment: [edit] your question rather than posting comments.